# Itertools combinations of multiple columns

Tags: python, combinations, product, python-itertools

I have this data

```
product color size
p1      Red   XXL
p2      Blue  XL
p3            L
              S
```

I want to make combinations from the columns as follows:

```
p1, Red, XXL
p1, Red, XL
.
.
p3, Blue, S
```

I tried make all columns in one list then use itertools.combinations but the result contains some unwanted data like:

```
p1, p2, p3
OR
Red, Blue, XXL
OR
XXL, XL, S ....
```

my code is:

```
df = read_csv('./GenerateProducts.csv', delimiter=',')
df_columns = df.columns.tolist()
```

```
list_data = DataFrame()
for i in df_columns:
    list_data = concat([list_data,df[i].dropna(axis=0)])
```

```
generated_products = DataFrame( combinations( list_data[0] ,len(df_columns) ) )
```

I am also trying to make it dynamic
I tried to make the columns into dict then use keys as pointer for the data but I did not know how to implement this logic, my experience with dict is too shallow

```
data = dict()
for i in df_columns:
    data[i] = df[i].dropna(axis=0)
```

I read a bout the itertools.product and that is why I made the dict also to use for loop to make same changes using the dict keys.

I think my execution with dict got me to confuse myself, any guidance

EDIT:

I got it to work

```
temp = []
for i in df_columns:
    temp += [data[i]]
    
final_df = DataFrame(product(*temp), columns=df_columns)
final_df
```

I am wondering is there more efficient way to accomplish the same result

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient way, using `itertools.product()`:

```
import itertools

prod1 = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
color1 = ['Red', 'Blue']
size1 = ['XXL', 'XL', 'L', 'S']
t1 = itertools.product(prod1, color1, size1)
for t in t1:
    print(t)
```

Output

```
('p1', 'Red', 'XXL')
('p1', 'Red', 'XL')
('p1', 'Red', 'L')
('p1', 'Red', 'S')
('p1', 'Blue', 'XXL')
('p1', 'Blue', 'XL')
('p1', 'Blue', 'L')
('p1', 'Blue', 'S')
('p2', 'Red', 'XXL')
('p2', 'Red', 'XL')
('p2', 'Red', 'L')
('p2', 'Red', 'S')
('p2', 'Blue', 'XXL')
('p2', 'Blue', 'XL')
('p2', 'Blue', 'L')
('p2', 'Blue', 'S')
('p3', 'Red', 'XXL')
('p3', 'Red', 'XL')
('p3', 'Red', 'L')
('p3', 'Red', 'S')
('p3', 'Blue', 'XXL')
('p3', 'Blue', 'XL')
('p3', 'Blue', 'L')
('p3', 'Blue', 'S')
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data is stored as follows in your dataframe (5 rows x 3 columns).

```
  product color size
0      p1   Red  XXL
1      p2  Blue   XL
2      p3          L
3                  S
```

## Using List Comprehension

You want to create a dataframe with a combination of each of these. You can do this using a list comprehension and then creating a dataframe from the results.

Here's how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['p1','p2','p3',''],
                   'color':['Red','Blue','',''],
                   'size':['XXL','XL','L','S']})

outlist = [(i,j,k)
           for i in df['product'] if i != ''
           for j in df['color'] if j != ''
           for k in df['size']]

newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=outlist,columns=['product','color','size'])
print (newdf)
```

The new dataframe will be:

```
   product color size
0       p1   Red  XXL
1       p1   Red   XL
2       p1   Red    L
3       p1   Red    S
4       p1  Blue  XXL
5       p1  Blue   XL
6       p1  Blue    L
7       p1  Blue    S
8       p2   Red  XXL
9       p2   Red   XL
10      p2   Red    L
11      p2   Red    S
12      p2  Blue  XXL
13      p2  Blue   XL
14      p2  Blue    L
15      p2  Blue    S
16      p3   Red  XXL
17      p3   Red   XL
18      p3   Red    L
19      p3   Red    S
20      p3  Blue  XXL
21      p3  Blue   XL
22      p3  Blue    L
23      p3  Blue    S
```

## Using product from itertools

Alternate approach is to use `product` from `itertools`

You can do this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['p1','p2','p3',''],
                   'color':['Red','Blue','',''],
                   'size':['XXL','XL','L','S']})

print (df)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(product(df['product'],
                                        df['color'],
                                        df['size'])),
                      columns=['product','color','size'])
new_df.drop(new_df[(new_df['product'] == '') | (new_df['color'] == '')].index, inplace = True)
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (new_df)
```

Note here that I have to remove rows that have `product = ''` or `size = ''` as the dataframe has these values and we want to ignore them.

The result of this will be:

```
   product color size
0       p1   Red  XXL
1       p1   Red   XL
2       p1   Red    L
3       p1   Red    S
4       p1  Blue  XXL
5       p1  Blue   XL
6       p1  Blue    L
7       p1  Blue    S
8       p2   Red  XXL
9       p2   Red   XL
10      p2   Red    L
11      p2   Red    S
12      p2  Blue  XXL
13      p2  Blue   XL
14      p2  Blue    L
15      p2  Blue    S
16      p3   Red  XXL
17      p3   Red   XL
18      p3   Red    L
19      p3   Red    S
20      p3  Blue  XXL
21      p3  Blue   XL
22      p3  Blue    L
23      p3  Blue    S
```